# Python import not working at all

Tags: python, python-3.x, quandl

I am using Python 3.6 running Python 32 bit. I am trying to use Quandl, but it is simply not importing no matter what i try. My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import Quandl

df = Quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
print(df.head())
```

I've tried using pip to install from the internet, and I've also installed it using a .whl file. The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/saeed/IdeaProjects/AI/q.py", line 2, in <module>
    import Quandl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Quandl'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

But I do have Quandl! What does this mean and how do I fix this? I have anaconda as well and I've also tried pip3 install Quandl.

Comment: Is python 3.6 your default python aka the one which pip would install the module for?

Comment: @Professor_Joykill yes it is. I have no other python installed.

Comment: If your Pandas module is importing properly, try to find where that is located and make sure Quandal is in the same place

Comment: @Darkspeed483 Can you try import quand1 (all with lower case) ?

Answer (score 0):

Import using a lowercase 'q'.

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl

df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with lower case

```
    import pandas as pd
    import quandl

    df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
    print(df.head())

I got
              Open    High     Low    Close      Volume  Ex-Dividend  \
Date                                                                   
2004-08-19  100.01  104.06   95.96  100.335  44659000.0          0.0   
2004-08-20  101.01  109.08  100.50  108.310  22834300.0          0.0   
2004-08-23  110.76  113.48  109.05  109.400  18256100.0          0.0   
2004-08-24  111.24  111.60  103.57  104.870  15247300.0          0.0   
2004-08-25  104.76  108.00  103.88  106.000   9188600.0          0.0   

            Split Ratio  Adj. Open  Adj. High   Adj. Low  Adj. Close  \
Date                                                                   
2004-08-19          1.0  50.159839  52.191109  48.128568   50.322842   
2004-08-20          1.0  50.661387  54.708881  50.405597   54.322689   
2004-08-23          1.0  55.551482  56.915693  54.693835   54.869377   
2004-08-24          1.0  55.792225  55.972783  51.945350   52.597363   
2004-08-25          1.0  52.542193  54.167209  52.100830   53.164113   

            Adj. Volume  
Date                     
2004-08-19   44659000.0  
2004-08-20   22834300.0  
2004-08-23   18256100.0  
2004-08-24   15247300.0  
2004-08-25    9188600.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use lower case:

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl
```

Example [here](https://www.quandl.com/tools/python)